# Apache Phoenix Array Modification

Tags: arrays, apache, apache-phoenix

I am using Phoenix for my project and I am stuck with Array types. My query is, suppose I have an array column in my table, I am inserting the data in that array, and after some time, weeks, months I will need to update the array, basically append/remove the data to/from it, basically modify the array but I am unable to find the solution for it. Could you help me with this?

I found this in the Limitations of array on Phoenix.apache.org:
--> Partial update of an array is currently not possible. Instead, the array may be manipulated on the client-side and then upserted back in its entirety.

Is there any work around for this?

Phoenix array type: https://phoenix.apache.org/array_type.html

Comment: Are you using the Query Server?  I think Arrays are only available in the thick client.

Comment: So is it not possible in Query Server?

Comment: that's what I found, you have to use the thick client